# How can i link my python game that i created to my html button?

Tags: python, html, web, frontend, backend

so im currently working on a school project where im building a website that promotes a game, and ive finished everything including the website and game, however i have no clue on how to add my game which is coded in python to my html button. The website name is "Shaytanfruit.com"

Answer (score 0):

You could always use [PyInstaller](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/) to turn your game into an executable (.exe / Mac-Linux binary) and have the button download the executable to the user's computer. The button's anchor tag would look something like this:

```html
<a href="game file path" download="game file name">Download Game</a>
```

And if you want to share the game's code, you could upload it to GitHub and then share the GitHub link as well.

If you want to run the Python code in the browser, you could try taking a look at [PyScript](https://pyscript.net/) or [Pyjs](http://pyjs.org/).

Comment: wouldnt i still have to run the code server side as well tho? and to do that wouldnt i have to configure flask into blue host? (my webserver)

Comment: If you're talking about the PyInstaller part, you only need to run PyInstaller once to make the executable Python game file. Then just host the file in the same directory as your html, css, etc. This is the easier method. If you go the PyScript / Pyjs route, yes, you'll have to configure your server and run the code server side. This is a more difficult method.